# Range slider not initialized properly when hidden

Tags: javascript, rangeslider

I have used a custom rangeslider found on github for my project in html php but the range slider is not initialized properly when its hidden at the start and i cant move it while the one thats visible on start is working fine any suggestions?

I have used this ---> http://rangeslider.js.org/